# Vue.js Firebase RealTime DB Rules - set rules for property modified by app function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, firebase-security

I hae a project database structure :

```
users
    isSuperMan: false
    isAdmin: false
     info:
        givenName:  xxxxxx
        address:   yyyyyy
        ....
     memberships:
         2018:
            paid: 10
            paidOn:  20198-01-01
            paymentType: 1
         2017:
            paid: 10
            paidOn:  20198-01-01
            paymentType: 1 
   ....
```

and my current Firebase rules are set to allow a logged user to create/update/delete his own data

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": false,
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As I am totally newbie with Firebase rules , I don't see how to set them to handle the following business cases , any help appreciated 
I wonder if I should not go for Firestore to handle such cases ?

1. logged user with Superadmin or Admin role ( true) can read/write ALL DATA
2. standard logged user can read/write his own info
3. standard user can read but cannot update/delete memberships
4. memberships data are written only when logged user is paying it

Comment: Answer to the first two below. I recommend trying a bit more based on that yourself, and posting back with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks I’ll try it ( already réal the doc) I am more concerned by Q3 and Q4 I don’t Know if they are well stated...

Answer (score 0):

To give someone with the admin role read access to the whole database, use these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val() === true"
  }
}
```

This read rule replaces what you currently have, since right now *all* signed in users can read the entire database.

To then allow each user to read/write their own info, modify the above to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val() === true",
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I highly recommend checking out the [Firebase documentation on security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/), specifically the section on [securing user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) (which covers step two I showed above), as well as the [great video explaining security rules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUBnlbjZFAI).